# Android Studio not starting on Linux (CentOS 6.6)

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, centos

I'm trying to run Android Studio on my CentOS 6.6. I've downloaded the Studio and as per Instructions when I move to directory /android-studio/bin/ and run the following command
./studio.sh

I got the following Exception

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./studio.sh 
No protocol specified
Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:39)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)

Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.initDisplay(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.access$200(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:65)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment$1.run(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:110)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.<clinit>(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:74)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
at sun.awt.X11.XToolkit.<clinit>(XToolkit.java:120)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at java.awt.Toolkit$2.run(Toolkit.java:869)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(Toolkit.java:861)
at java.awt.Toolkit.getEventQueue(Toolkit.java:1756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.isDispatchThread(EventQueue.java:1025)
at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread(SwingUtilities.java:1360)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.reclaim(StyleContext.java:454)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:311)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.addAttribute(StyleSheet.java:578)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.addAttribute(StyleContext.java:1501)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.setName(StyleContext.java:1312)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext$NamedStyle.<init>(StyleContext.java:1259)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.addStyle(StyleContext.java:107)
at javax.swing.text.StyleContext.<init>(StyleContext.java:87)
at javax.swing.text.html.StyleSheet.<init>(StyleSheet.java:166)
at javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit.getStyleSheet(HTMLEditorKit.java:392)
at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.<clinit>(UIUtil.java:97)
at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.start(PluginManager.java:71)
... 6 more


Also, an UI exception occurred on attempt to show above message:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:191)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.<clinit>(RepaintManager.java:212)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4796)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.setEditable(JTextComponent.java:1807)
at javax.swing.text.JTextComponent.<init>(JTextComponent.java:319)
at javax.swing.JEditorPane.<init>(JEditorPane.java:197)
at javax.swing.JTextPane.<init>(JTextPane.java:90)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:231)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.showMessage(Main.java:217)
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:86)
```

I have no idea what to do now. here are my Environment variables and Java version.

```
[root@localhost /]# javac -version
javac 1.8.0_45
[root@localhost /]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.5.5.3.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
[root@localhost /]# echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64
[root@localhost /]# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont know exactly but the problem is $JAVA_HOME is changing itself automatically. so whenever I've to start android-studio I've to set it to correct path again and again like:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/home/path/to/jdk1.8.0_45
```

Answer (score 0):

seems u didnt install the java-devel package or try to reinstall.
once u did, the 'JAVA_HOME' will be something as below:

`JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java`

not

`/usr/lib/jvm/jre`

if `JAVA_HOME` still not right, just set it by urself.

Comment: @Abdul Mohsin well, then try to check these files, ```~/.bashrc```, ```~/.bashrc``` , ```/etc/init.d/rc.local``` or somewhere it set the ```$JAVA_HOME```. i'm using OpenSuse, not familiar with CentOS. sry about that.